# Git post-receive hook writen as a POSIX shell script (utilising a named pipe)

Tags: shell, git, signal-handling

This is my first piece of code to post here. I wrote this script as a
post-receive hook for a Git repository but I’m not so concerned with the Git
parts (I’d like to have the part marked with `TODO` working but it’s not a
priority).

It’s my first time to use either *named pipes* or the `trap` command to clean
up temporary files. As the first comment states, I’ve written the script to be
POSIX compatible – though I’ve only run it using Bash in POSIX mode.

Finally, I’m also happy to get feedback on any stylistic issues or common
conventions that I could be using.

```
#!/bin/sh
# This shell script is POSIX compatible.  If using Bash, the use of named pipes
# could be replaced by process substitution (see further comments).

# This Git post-receive hook:
# 1. Sends an email to the project collaborators with details of commits being
# pushed to this repository.
# 2. Checks out changes in the branches into different working directories to
# be served as virtual sites by Apache and provides immediate feedback (on
# stdout) to the git user pushing to the repository.

readonly PROJECT=project_name
readonly RECIPIENTS="alice@example.com,bob@example.com"

# Send email message with info about the changes being pushed.

# Keep track of which branch(es) are being pushed to since `refname` is only
# available while a line from stdin is being processed.
# Create an "empty" variable for each branch that may be checked out.
master_branch=''
beta_branch=''

# A named pipe is used to store the details of each commit from each branch
# being pushed. The original idea was to pipe the output of the do...while loop
# into the mail command. However, using a pipe means that the first part of the
# pipe (the loop) is executed in a subshell environment with the result that
# changes made to shell variables are lost when the subshell terminates.  A
# named pipe (or process substitution) is required to avoid creating a subshell
# whose variables aren't visible outside the subshell.
# See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024

readonly NAMED_PIPE=/tmp/${PROJECT}_pipe.$$
# Set trap to ensure the named pipe is cleaned up no matter how the script exits.
trap "rm -f $NAMED_PIPE" EXIT
# Create the named pipe if it doesn't already exist (it shouldn't).
if [ ! -p $NAMED_PIPE ]; then
    mkfifo $NAMED_PIPE
fi

# Run the mail command in the background so it stays open for as long as the
# named pipe has data.
mail "$RECIPIENTS" -s "Pushed commits for $PROJECT" < $NAMED_PIPE &

# For each branch being pushed to, there's a corresponding line on stdin.
while read oldrev newrev refname
do
    printf "\n====================================================\n"
    # If a new branch is being pushed to; this would result in a
    # `fatal: Invalid symmetric difference expression" error.
    # In this case, $oldrev is set to 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
    # http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3511057/git-receive-update-hooks-and-new-branches
    if [ "$oldrev" != 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 ]; then
        # Alternative solution is to use Bash to compare SHAs as hexadecimal
        # numbers using `-eq` but string comparison is simpler & more portable.
        printf "\nNew commits for branch: %s" ${refname##*/}
        printf "\n----------------------------------------\n\n"
        git log --no-color --stat ${oldrev}...${newrev}
        # git rev-list "$oldrev..$newrev"
    else
        printf "\n\nNew branch: %s\n" ${refname##*/}
        # TODO: Show the commits in the new branch, i.e., revisions
        # reachable from $newrev but not from any pre-existing branches.
    fi

    # Record which branch(es) are being updated.
    if [ "${refname##*/}" = "master" ]; then
        master_branch="true"
    elif [ "${refname##*/}" = "development" ]; then
        beta_branch="true"
    fi
done > $NAMED_PIPE
# done > >(mail "$RECIPIENTS" -s "Pushed commits for $PROJECT") # Bash process substitution.


# Check out the branches to their appropriate directories while printing
# command output to stdout. Note that one or more branches may have changes.

if [ "$master_branch" ]; then
    echo  Checking out the master branch into primary_site.staging
    git --work-tree /var/www/vhosts/primary_site.staging/ checkout -f master
    echo
fi

if [ "$beta_branch" ]; then
    echo  Checking out the development branch into beta_site.staging
    git --work-tree /var/www/vhosts/beta_site.staging/ checkout -f development
    echo
fi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Make sure your script will stop early: `set -o errexit -o noclobber -o nounset`, but be aware of the [caveats](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105).
- The fact that the `master_branch` and `beta_branch` variables are mutually exclusive is a hint that they can be merged:

  ```
  branch="${refname##*/}"

  case "$branch" in
      master)
          ...
          ;;
      development)
          ...
          ;;
  esac
  ```
- You should use `mktemp` rather than PID to create a guaranteed unique file. A common best practice is to create a temporary *directory* since it's an atomic operation.
- [Use More Quotes™!](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCQQFjAAahUKEwj8mNus7fvIAhVBbRQKHcsdBwU&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmywiki.wooledge.org%2FQuotes&usg=AFQjCNGCW99ARZBuQx2ZPTMwe3zrVlIcnw)

Other than this, it's very well written.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the feedback.

Setting `errexit`, etc. makes sense and the case statement is cleaner and more readable. However, the temporary file I’m creating is a named pipe so I can’t use `mktemp` (AFAIK `mknod` is the only alternative to `mkfifo` for creating a named pipe).

Finally, I’ve been looking at some of the scripts submitted to this site and reviewed by Janos; he/she warns against over-quoting so I’m trying to tread a middle ground. :)